How to use dynamic importing on a Next.js route group
When having a set of data (json, ts) in a dynamic group: app/(blog-articles)/first.ts if you want to dynamically import it: let's say that you're using a useEffect with the dynamic import, Next.js throws an error
I've tried:
useEffect(()=>{
  const blogFound = await import(`./(blog-articles)/${params['blog-id'].ts`});

but it doesn't work as Next.js throws an error, I'm actually figuring out the answer, check bellow.

What error does it throw?

I can't actually reproduce it now, weird, I would delete this post but it might help someone!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I've figure out that you just need to escape the brackets:
useEffect(()=>{
  const blogFound = await import(`./\(blog-articles\)/${params['blog-id'].ts`});

I hope everyone finds this useful

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I'm glad you found a solution, but the issue seems to be that it was a typo.

no, it's not a typo, the issue is that 'import' doesn't work if there are group paths unless you escape the bracket characters

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading seems to disagree with this answer?
